# JetBrains - Download spell dictionary

Tags: intellij-idea, spell-checking, jetbrains-ide

Where can I find dictionaries of other language in order to add to the dictionaries of spelling check of may JetBrains IDE?

Comment: Try googling this

Comment: I found that i should download my own dictionary, but I m looking for official dictionaries by JetBrains! @Kai